# How do I create the update statement that checks if a vlue is lower than the reorder_point attribute for a product

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Utilize the Outdoor Clubs & Product database to create a trigger “product_reorder_au” that is associated with an update operation on the product table. The trigger checks to see whether during the update of the quantity_in_stock attribute, if its value gets lower than the reorder_point attribute value for a product. When this situation occurs, the trigger automatically inserts a new purchase order in the purchase_order table. The new purchase order will use the existing supplier_no attribute value for the product in the product table, and the quantity attribute value will be same as the reorder_qty value for the product in the product table. Save the trigger source as a script file.

This is what the product table looks like

[image]

So far this is what I have but I am just generally confused on how to update the table and add in what I am guessing would be an if then statement to only update when the `reorderpoint` is lower than the `quantitiy_in_stock`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_reorder_au
AFTER UPDATE OF product
for each row
begin
IF Quantity_In_Stock < Reorder_Point
THEN
    INSERT INTO Purchase_Order (Po_No, Po_Date, Product_Id, Quantity, Supplier_id)
    VALUES ( );
END IF;
END;
```

--Test Script

```
update product
set quantity_in_stock = 5
where product_id = 10012;
```

Attached in the other tables[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BEFORE` trigger not `AFTER` trigger. See below:

--Table Preparation

```
CREATE TABLE product_1 (
    quantity_in_stock   NUMBER,
    reorder_point       NUMBER,
    product_id          NUMBER,
    supplier_id         NUMBER,
    reorder_qty         NUMBER
);

    INSERT INTO product_1 VALUES (
        20,
        5,
        10010,
        500,
        25
    )

CREATE TABLE purchase_order (
    po_no         NUMBER,
    po_date       DATE,
    product_id    NUMBER,
    quantity      NUMBER,
    supplier_id   NUMBER
);

SQL> Select * from product_1;

QYT_IN_STOCK  REORDER_PNT PRDT_ID  SUPP_ID  RERDR_QTY
-----------   ----        -----    -----    -----
 4            5       10010 500 25
```

--Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_reorder_au BEFORE
    UPDATE ON product_1
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.quantity_in_stock < old.reorder_point )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO purchase_order (
        po_no,
        po_date,
        product_id,
        quantity,
        supplier_id
    ) VALUES (
        1, --Populate this coulmn by a sequence or by some logic
        SYSDATE,
        :old.product_id,
        :old.reorder_qty,
        :old.supplier_id
    );
END;
```

Execution:

```
SQL> UPDATE product_1
     SET
        quantity_in_stock = 4
     WHERE product_id = 10010;

SQL> SELECT * FROM purchase_order;
PO_NO PO_DATE       PRODUCT_ID  QTY     SUPP_ID
----- -------       --------   ----      -------
1     25-10-18  10010       25       500
```